# FusionLocationProvider not getting location update when application went background

Tags: android, fusedlocationproviderapi, android-fusedlocation, fusedlocationproviderclient

I'm using FusionLocationProviderClient to get the location update periodically in the background. It's working fine. But, Having some issue in Oreo. Location update stops as soon as application goes background.

```
mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context);
            mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(createLocationRequest(), getPendingIntent(context)).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Location update registered successfully");
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Location update failed to register " + e);
                }
            });

private LocationRequest createLocationRequest() {
        LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();

        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest.setMaxWaitTime(MAX_WAIT_TIME_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        return mLocationRequest;
    }
```

Comment: may be need request permissions

Comment: @Tigo2018 I've provided location permission to app.